# Unable to make LibreOffice online build

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libreoffice

I am trying to build libreOffice online by following the readme here https://github.com/LibreOffice/online in LoolWsd folder.

When i run make command i get this exception

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre
```

Can you please tell what can be done here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pcre-dev, what it´s telling you basically is that it can´t find that library. Look at it this way, cannot find Library:pcre.